# Measurable functions to the extended real number set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let (X,S) be a measurable space.Suppose f is a function from from X to [-inf,inf]  such that inverse image of (a,inf) belongs to S for all a in R. Is f S-measurable function?

For f to be S measurable function inverse image of (a,inf] has to be in S but since the inverse image of the singleton set containing infinity is the intersection of inverse images of (n,inf) where n belongs to natural number set.
Inverse image of (a,inf] also belongs to S.Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the hypothesis in the first paragraph. In the second para you changed $(a, \infty) $ to $(a, \infty]$.

This is not true. Let $A$ be a set which is not in $S$ and $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x \in A$, $f(x)=-\infty$ for all $x \in X \setminus A$. Then $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is the empty set for each real number $a$, but $f$ is not measurable.

If you have $(a, \infty]$ instead of $(a, \infty)$ the your argument is correct.

Comment: My question is if f is a function such that inverse image of (a,inf) is in S for all a in R, is it true that the inverse image of (a,inf] is also in S?

Comment: Also why is inverse image of (a, inf) empty set in your answer?

Comment: My $f$ takes only the values $\pm \infty$. How can $f(x) \in (a, \infty)$ for any $x$? For your first comment note that $f^{-1}(0,\infty]=A$ which is not in $S$.

Comment: So my understanding of " f(x)= inf " means that f(x)>n for any natural number n which implies that x belongs to inverse image of (n,inf) for all n. Is this wrong?

Comment: You are making a mistake. If $f(x)=\infty$ then it is true that $f(x) >n$ for all natural numbers $n$ but that does not mean that $f(x)$ belongs to $(n, \infty)$. This is because this interval contains only **real numbers**.  It does not include $\infty$.  @pooja